# Write in textfile in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

hi i am trying to make a delphi program that writes to a text file
so far failed to achieve all but one detail is that the program writes well when used several times

```
hi
hi
hi
```

and I need to do so

```
hihihi
```

the code that I have so far is this

```
TForm1.Button1Click procedure (Sender: TObject);
var
   File: TextFile;

begin

   AssignFile (file, 'aca.txt');
   / / FileMode: = fmOpenWrite;

   if FileExists ('aca.txt') then
     Append (file)
   else
     Rewrite (file);

   Writeln (file, 'hi');
   CloseFile (file);

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Write` instead of `WriteLn`.

Answer (score 2):

Try TStrings

```
var
  ALines: TStrings;
begin
  ALines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ALines.LoadFromFile('textfile.txt');

    Alines.Add('New Content');

    ALines.SaveToFile('textfile.txt');
  finally
    ALines.Free;
  end;
end;
```